# Spring hibernate domain saving not working with postgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was saving the `Executive` domain object which has a relationship with `UserAccount` , but there are some errors throwing while saving the object:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
    Unsaved transient entity: ([com.sar.customerplus.entity.UserAccount#0])
    Dependent entities: ([[com.sar.customerplus.entity.MarketingExecutive#300]])
    Non-nullable association(s): ([com.sar.customerplus.entity.MarketingExecutive.userAccount])
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.sar.customerplus.entity.MarketingExecutive.userAccount -> com.sar.customerplus.entity.UserAccount; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.sar.customerplus.entity.MarketingExecutive.userAccount -> com.sar.customerplus.entity.UserAccount
```

**Executive**

```
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id", nullable = false)
private UserAccount userAccount;
```

**UserAccount**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "useraccount_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
private List<Role> roles;
```

**Role**

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_role_gen", sequenceName = "seq_role")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_role_gen")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 11)
private Long roleId;

@Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
private String roleName;
```

And i was using the executive domain using:

```
 UserAccount account=new UserAccount();
 account.setUserName(userName);
 account.setPassword(password);
 Role role=roleService.findRoleByRoleName("ROLE_EXECUTIVE");
 List<Role>roles=new ArrayList<>();
 roles.add(role);
 account.setRoles(roles);

 MarketingExecutive executive=new MarketingExecutive();
 executive.setName(name);
 executive.setUserAccount(account);
 marketingExecutiveService.saveMarketingExecutive(executive);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> transient instance must be saved before current operation

This means that you're persisting an instance of `Executive` which has a relationship with a `transient` `UserAccount` instance, an instance of `UserAccount` which has **not** persisted yet.

You either should persist your newly instantiated (`transient`) `UserAccount` before persisting `Executive`:

```
UserAccount account = new UserAccount();
...
accountRepository.save(account);
...
executive.setUserAccount(account);
marketingExecutiveService.saveMarketingExecutive(executive);
```

or add a suitable `Cascade` option to your `Executive` entity:

```
// other annotations
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private UserAccount userAccount;
```